# How to clear element value in xslt if the value is a string

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I just wanna clear a element value if element value is a specific string value

Input xml

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>BOLD</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Desired Output

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C/>
  </B>
</A>
```

my xslt looks like following which doesn't work it just clears everything

```
 <xsl:template match="A/B/C/text()">
    <xsl:if test="text()='BOLD'">
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

<!--Copy the rest of the document as it is-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Please help thanks

Comment: I just tried your xslt on provided input and it seems to be working exactly as you want. So if there is any problem it is probably elsewhere in your code what you didn't provide. BTW - condition on text()='BOLD' you could also write into match attribute of template (just my personal choice).

Comment: @JirkaŠ. The original input was mal-formed, and its impossible for it to spit anything out. I'm not sure what you did, but it couldn't have worked.

Comment: You are right - I corrected the xml to be well formed first and didn't mention it in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you've started with an identity template there's really no need to use an explicit `xsl:if`, just put the condition in the match expression of an empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="A/B/C/text()[. = 'BOLD']"/>
```

Text nodes that are not under an `A/B/C` or whose content is not `BOLD` will be handled by the identity template and copied as normal.

The caveat with using `text()` in your match expressions is that it means the template is looking at only one text node at a time, and only at text that is directly inside the `C` element. If the `C` can have other content you will get some odd edge cases:

```
<C>BOLD<br/></C> --> <C><br/></C>
<C><b>B</b>OLD</C> --> unchanged
<C><b>BOLD</b></C> --> unchanged
```

If you want to treat the full text under the C as one unit regardless of child elements then you need something more like

```
<xsl:template match="C[. = 'BOLD']">
  <C/>
</xsl:template>
```

without mentioning `text()`. This would clear all three of my examples above.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your first template isn't outputting anything if the text *isn't* `"BOLD"`, so if the text is bold, its spits out nothing, otherwise it still spits out nothing. also, the `text()` node won't have its own text.

So, replace the first template it with this, and it should work fine.

```
  <xsl:template match="A/B/C/text()">
    <xsl:if test="not(.='BOLD')">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

And applied to this:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>Bold</C>
    <C>BOLD</C>
    <C>Italic</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Gives this:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>Bold</C>
    <C/>
    <C>Italic</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this issue is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[text()='BOLD']">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```